# MySQL: select sum of column having specific values

Tags: mysql, sql

What I'm trying to do is to select a specific amount of tickets (max 2) and every person that has the sum of the number of tickets *less of 3* and the valid field has to be != 'e'

I have this table:

| ID | id_person | nr_tickets | valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 220 | 1 | s |
| 2 | 220 | 1 | s |
| 3 | 330 | 2 | s |
| 4 | 330 | 1 | e |
| 5 | 331 | 1 | s |
| 6 | 220 | 2 | s |
| 7 | 441 | 1 | s |
| 8 | 442 | 2 | s |
| 9 | 443 | 1 | s |
| 10 | 444 | 1 | s |
| 11 | 445 | 2 | s |

Here is what I did:

```
SELECT m.id, m.id_person, m.nr_tickets, m.valid
FROM   table m
JOIN   table m1 ON m1.id <= m.id 
WHERE  m.nr_tickets > 0 
GROUP  BY m.id
HAVING SUM(case when m.valid != 'e' then m1.nr_tickets end) <= 10
```

This query gives me

| ID | id_person | nr_tickets | valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 220 | 1 | s |
| 2 | 220 | 1 | s |
| 3 | 330 | 2 | s |
| 5 | 331 | 1 | s |
| 6 | 220 | 2 | s |
| 7 | 441 | 1 | s |
| 8 | 442 | 2 | s |

As you can see the query it's almost right, the thing is that the person **220** in the results has the sum of the tickets is greater than 2.

What I'm trying to achieve is to bypass the ID 6, and to have instead the ID 9

Comment: I think that if you use `GROUP BY m.id` every item in the `select`-clause exept `m.id` has to be an agregate. This will not solve your problem, but it is a step to a correct statement.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select `id`,`id_person`, sum(`nr_tickets`) as `nr_tickets`, `valid` 
from `test`
group by `id_person`
having sum(`nr_tickets`) < 3 and `valid`!="e"
```

Output:

```
id  id_person   nr_tickets  valid
5      331        1           s
7      441        1           s
8      442        2           s
9      443        1           s
10     444        1           s
11     445        2           s
```

Comment: you're almost there what I need to do is to limit the total sum of the tickets to be less or equal to a specified amount

Comment: Hint: the id-column is not helpful, because it is one random value out of all in this statement. If there are other values for valid than "e" and "s", then for valid there is the same problem.